# how to install Angular 2 into codeigniter without node.js/npm (manually download)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codeigniter

I know that if I install node.js on Windows all problems will be gone but i'm worry or not sure that the share hosting won't let us do so many things,

> `is there any solution to manually download all Angular 2 required
>   files and put them in a CodeIngiter project?`

Angular offical and other sites only show how to install with node.js / npm,  there is no manual download file.
is it possible to do ? or node.js / npm is the only way to use Angular 2 ?

Thank you in advance

@Vali S i have 1 question does i need to run `npm start` cmd to let it compile angular 2 ? no auto compile without running `npm start` ?

Comment: Depends on the context. But given your first question as a context, that would not be necessary (no **npm start** I mean...). Node.js and CodeIgniter (php) are executed server side, while angular.js, client side. So if your manual angular installation is ok, there's no need for node.js anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Including Angular into your app has nothing to do with the back end framework. Also, node.js npm is a packet manager that downloads the sources and installs them where you need them, but installing manually is usually quite easy too. All you have to do is to include the link into the page header, [like this](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/downloading):

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to save it on the server and load it from there, you can for example, open the link in your browser, right click and **Save as..**, then link to the location on the server, like this:`<script src="https://example.com/public/js/angular.min.js"></script>`.

**EDIT :**

Although it is possible and easy to manually install Angularjs library, managing a complex project manually may not be so easy. That's where the node npm package manager may come in handy. What you actually need is for you to figure out. To help decide what you need, check out these links:

- https://material.angularjs.org/latest/
- https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#angularjs
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2
- https://code.angularjs.org/

**NOTE :**
IF you develop on Windows using npm, there's nothing to worry about, you only have to clone your sources as they are to the production server. Everything would be installed.

Comment: thz but does `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js` is version 1x not 2x ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2 : angular 2 is still beta(currently beta.17, that's what you get with **npm install angular2**), you can use it though. You can also choose from the many stable versions here: https://code.angularjs.org.